# What is the "format register" string for at the top of JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, systemjs

I see in various JavaScript files lately the following string at the top:

```
"format register";
```

What is this for?

I see it in angular 2 and systemJS library files.

Comment: Pretty amazing .. was curious myself and did google search and this 4 minute old post already shows up in search index

Comment: I'm guessing that this indicates (to some kind of multi-format loader -- SystemJS, maybe?) that the module is intended to be loaded with [`System.register`](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/blob/master/docs/system-register.md)

Comment: Hmm. From what I've read, my impression is that SystemJS normally looks for the presence of `SystemJS.register()` at the top of the file to detect a SystemJS module, but the TypeScript compiler inserts some code before that and messes up the heuristic. The "system register" comment may somehow end up above the generated code, and is either explicitly allowed as an alternative, or just happens to match the same regex and so is being used as a temporary hack.

Answer (score 3):

> By adding 'format register'; at the top of all ts files the issue
>   seems to be resolved but I suppose that it only helps SystemJS
>   understand/load the modules correctly..

It just reduces bug as stated. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3937) is the orignal conversation that got it started. But it just makes SystemJS Load correctly. Infact it got very known that SystemJS Made a module that made that not neccesary, by adding this:

```
System.config({
  meta: { main: { format: 'register' } }
});
```

That is explained more [here](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/595).

[Reason](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md) to use it.
To conclude, "format register", is used to make sure SystemJS Loads its modules correctly, and in order! Hope this helped!

Comment: Hey Amanuel, I see you've been trying to add the [tag:codecademy] tag to some questions.  Please note that this tag is too general to be useful on Stack Overflow, and should not be used.  Please do not add this tag to any posts as editing it in adds noise to the Suggested Edit queue and the question itself.  If you have any questions, please feel free to reach out to me in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chatroom.

Answer (score 2):

Great question, I was intrigued and didn't know myself so went an a quest.

It appears it's a way of ES5 code to support ES6 style modules.

> System.register can be considered as a new module format designed to support the exact semantics of ES6 modules within ES5. It is a format that was developed out of collaboration and is supported as a module output in Traceur (as instantiate), Babel and TypeScript (as system). All dynamic binding and circular reference behaviors supported by ES6 modules are supported by this format. In this way it acts as a safe and comprehensive target format for the polyfill path into ES6 modules.

https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/wiki/System.register-Explained

**Example usage:**

To add some more detail, here is an example in the angular 1.x upgrade notes, which shows the example of format register in action, but rather than a comment at the top of the file, it's instead in the config declaration.

`System.config({
  packages: {
    'base/app/js': {
      defaultExtension: false,
      format: 'register',
...`

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

**Reason to use it**

> When the module format is not set, automatic regular-expression-based detection is used. This module format detection is never completely accurate, but caters well for the majority use cases.

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md

Using "format register" at the top of the file is one of the ways which gives the format detection a hint.

Comment: sad part is you did search that OP could have done themselves and probably found same resource

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @charlietfl I've added some more detail. The answer I've supplied although yes is from a search result it is from authoritative documentation which without the right keywords of what to search for is surprisingly tricky to come across. It's got a snippet illustrating the OP's direct question with further information linked.

Comment: Hi @charlietfl hopefully this adds enough detail worthy of a useful answer. :-)

Comment: No worries @charlietfl there was room for improvement, feedback is always good :-)